# Vs2013 default theme bootstrap background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2013, background-color

I am using Visual Studio MVC web application with out of the box theme.

I try to change the navbar background-color and body background color in bootstrap.css.

In the css file on visual studio I see the color codes I entered but when I run the app and page inspect it on chrome the css is back to original state.

How can I change the body background color and navbar background color in bootstrap.css ?

I have bootstrap 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the visual studio and now it works. Just changing the body tags background-color and restarting the VS was enough